# To what extent should I embellish on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin, job-description, title

I work for a very large company with lots of engineers at lots of different levels.

Recently, some of my coworkers have found me on LinkedIn. Of the four people who requested me over my time with the company, all four have their job title publicly incorrect.

Three of them, whose real job title is "Jr. Software Engineer" have their title as "Software Engineer", and one of them who is actually at my level of "Software Engineer" has his title as "Sr. Software Engineer".

Should I embellish my own title? Should I tell someone or call them out?

Comment: Zero extent. This stuff will ultimately get back to a potential employer. It seems like a small thing, and it will definitely harm how you're viewed at a potential new employer. If I did a verification of employment and discovered this discrepancy, it would be enough for me to disqualify a candidate.

Comment: 1. Don't embellish your profile. 2. Keep your eyes on your own paper. It's doubtful that what they're doing is illegal, and as such, really isn't any of your concern.

Comment: It's just LinkDin not a legal document or job application, most of the peoples profiles I know seem to be fanciful rubbish, no real difference from facebook, just a social media platform

Answer (score 1):

> Should I embellish my own title?

No.

I firmly believe that your title and dates of employment on your resume should match the title in your company's HR system or on offer letters. This makes sure that the information is relevant and useful to someone performing a background check. It also reduces work when you import a resume onto various forms if that is an available feature. It also gives you a useful place to go to look up past employers, dates of service, and calculate the amount of professional experience that you have easily.

I follow this advice for my resume in any format - LinkedIn, Stack Overflow Careers, Word documents, or PDF versions. The consistency just makes things much easier if you need to provide different versions, someone stumbles across multiple copies from different sources, and for future maintenance.

> Should I tell someone or call them out?

I wouldn't.

It doesn't seem like its worthwhile to spend the energy on this and potentially strain a relationship. Maybe it will never be a problem for them. If it is, though, they can deal with it and maybe learn. Or maybe they are willing to put in the extra time and effort to communicate why what they present on their resume is different than the formal records of employment.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to put a descriptive job title over your official title. Nothing wrong with putting "Software Engineer" instead of "Jr. Software Engineer".

You are leaving off your seniority title and that is perfectly fine because you aren't claiming to be Junior, Mid, Senior or anything else.

Putting "Sr. Software Engineer" would be intentionally misleading unless you were officially a senior. So that would be wrong.

If you find someone lying just ignore it. It's not going to effect you, and you don't know if the employer gave them permission to claim that title. Calling them out just puts you at  risk of looking like a trouble maker. They will be found out eventually.

So it's fine to embellish by choosing what information to share, that's just called marketing yourself. - But don't embellish in such a way you lie to or mislead the employer.

In my experience of the tech industry, if you leave off "Jr" and just use "Software Engineer", even with a background check, few employers will care or interpret that as a lie...

Comment: I would disagree with this, and would not consider that a lie. If someone listed their title as "software engineer" I would ask: "what level, were you junior, mid..." - Software engineer is a title, the jr/sr is just a seniority label. ---  I am not saying you're wrong but I don't agree, I think it's entirely opinion based so it can be seen both ways.